# finding a value of parameter p of the geometric distribution

Tags: probability

The number of items bought by people entering a shop is random variable X that has a geometric starting at 0 with mean 1.5. Find the value of the parameter p of the geometric distribution and write down the p.g.f of X.

So E(X) = $\frac{p}{q}$ = 1.5

Can be worked out as: 2p=3(1-p) which equals 5p=3 which equals p=3/5=0.6
^How is this line worked out???^ How do we get to p=0.6 in a simple form? Could someone break it down further?

Comment: @WATER I must use G^0(p) as the geometric starting point is 0.The mean equation for this is above. P over Q. it is 1 over P for G^1(p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pmf of this version of a geometric distribution is $P(X=k)= q^k\cdot p \ \ \ \forall \ k= 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$, where $q=1-p$.

The expected value is $\mathbb E(X)=\frac{q}p=\frac{1-p}p$.

So $q$ is at the *numerator* and $p$ at the *denominator*. In your case the equation is

$\frac{1-p}p=1.5$

Multiplying the equation by $p$.

$1-p=1.5p$

Adding $p$ on both sides of the equation.

$1=2.5p$

$1=\frac{25}{10}p$

Multiplying the equation by $10$ and dividing it by $25$.

$ \frac{10}{25}=\underbrace{\frac{25}{10}\cdot \frac{10}{25}}_{=1}p$

$ \frac{10}{25}=p$

Expanding the fraction by $4$

$p=\frac{40}{100}=0.4$

Comment: ah great. This makes some sense. Although are you able to help me workout how the working was used above in the question? The answer for p is definitely 0.6 as I have took the answer from the original question from the answer book. For example, I'm not sure how the first part gets too 2p=3(1=p)

Comment: @ShazzaNic I´m sure that my result is right, since $\mathbb E(Y)=\frac{q}p$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Moments_and_cumulants). Nevertheless here is the calculation $2p=3(1-p) $ Multiplying out the brackets $2p=3-3p$ Adding $3p$ on both sides. $5p=3$ Dividing the equation yb $5$: $p=\frac{3}5=\frac{6}{10}=0.6$

Comment: ahh, makes sense! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @ShazzaNic You are welcome. It would please me if  you  would accept the answer.